# How to construct a query to return one result

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

in google's bigquery, Lets say I want to try and find an exact match (eg: by ZIP code), but if I fail, get another closer match based on say city+state+country.

So something like:

```
select *
from locations
where 
  Target_Type = "Postal Code" and
  Name = "L4A" and
  Country_Code = "CA"
  or
  (
  Name = "Toronto" and
  Target_Type = "City" and
  Country_Code = "CA"
  )
```

This returns two, and I want to get only the FIRST match, and the second ONLY if the first match has failed.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dummy field to indicate which one have more priority. And use `UNION` to have both searchs.

```
 SELECT '1st Match' as priority, <some fields>
 FROM YourTable
 WHERE <some conditions>
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '2st Match' as priority, <some fields>
 FROM YourTable
 WHERE <other conditions>
 ORDER BY  priority, <other sort field> -- in case query return multiple result
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Are you sure your answer applies to bigquery? I get an error Unrecognized token UNION.

Comment: Im not familiar with big query, but looks like support `UNION ALL` https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-union-queries-in-google-bigquery/

Comment: @Carmageddon It should have worked. Try adding #standardSQL right at the beginning of the query

Comment: Both of you were right - I had the legacy option ticked in :)

Comment: Accepted this one instead of the alternative, as it is more self descriptive and easy to follow through

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery Standard SQL  - yet another option to consider - it allows you to add more "rules" than just two as in your example

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH locations AS (
    SELECT "Postal Code" AS Target_Type, "L4A" AS Name, "CA" AS Country_Code UNION ALL
    SELECT "City", "Toronto", "CA"
)
SELECT *
FROM locations
WHERE (
  Target_Type = "Postal Code" AND
  Name = "L4A" AND
  Country_Code = "CA"
) OR (
  Name = "Toronto" AND
  Target_Type = "City"AND
  Country_Code = "CA"
)
ORDER BY CASE Target_Type 
  WHEN "Postal Code" THEN 1 
  WHEN "City" THEN 2 
  ELSE 3 END 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: HI MB, you wrote a book, does my answer work in BigQuery? or Im way off?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - yes - that syntax should work with BigQuery